# I have a problem with loading a element from Blazor Website

Tags: c#, html, jquery, blazor, signalr

I have a very stupid problem and just can't get ahead.
I want to use jquery to get a single HTML element from my Blazor website and display it. This works fine on other websites, but my Blazor website is having problems.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<base href="https://example-website.com/" />
<div id="success"></div>
<script>
$( "#success" ).load( "https://example-website.com/landingPage" );
</script>
```

So far so good, unfortunately I get the following error in the ServerLog:

> 2022-08-17 21:36:04.8054|0|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub|Circuit initialization failed System.ArgumentException: The URI 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic' is not contained by the base URI 'https://example-website.com/'.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager.Validate(Uri baseUri, String uri)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager.set_Uri(String value)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager.Initialize(String baseUri, String uri)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitFactory.CreateCircuitHostAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 components, CircuitClientProxy client, String baseUri, String uri, ClaimsPrincipal user, IPersistentComponentStateStore store)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ComponentHub.StartCircuit(String baseUri, String uri, String serializedComponentRecords, String applicationState)

I hope I could tell you my problem well and you can help me :)

Comment: Where is this coming from? "https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic" It looks like something is trying to navigate there

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in JScript and JQuery?  You need to provide much more context.  So far you've just shown a simple JS script.

Comment: @EricKing I`m running this code from the w3school try it editor.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I want to display only 1 div from one website in another.

Comment: I`m getting this from google chrome: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed."